# Parse Cloud Code Iterating Results Issue

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm using parse and trying to make a cloud code query to handle this:

I want to query a table and then iterate over all the results and check if column1 > column2.  I'm not sure there is a way to do that with query constraints so I am doing a for loop over the results.

However my issue is when I return goodRides in my iOS app I get this error:

```
"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
```

If I return results without iterating and parsing which ones I want that works fine so I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong in my loop iteration.

Here is my code:

```
q.find()
    .then(results => {
      var goodRides;
      for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
      {
        if(results[i].get("availableSeats") > results[i].get("occupiedSeats")){
          goodRides.push(results[i]);
        }
      }
      return goodRides;
    })
    .then(rides => {
      res.success(rides);
    })
    .catch(function (err){
      res.log.error("Error");
    });
```

My issue is when I try to push(results[i] onto the goodRides variable everything breaks.  How can I iterate the results and extract only the indices I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would write this:

```js
q.find()
.then(results => Promise.resolve(
  results.filter((result) => result.get('availableSeats') > result.get('occupiedSeats'))
))
.then(rides => res.success(rides))
.catch(err => res.error(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

`goodRides` must be initialized to an array in order to push to it...

```
var goodRides = [];
```